# C - create members of struct in loop?

Tags: c, loops, struct, initialization

I am new to C programing and want to write a program that reads a line of integers and then creates a member of a struct for each of them. Here is a simplified example:

Let’s say this is the line: *23 4 12 56 78 *

and the struct looks like this:

```
struct structure
{
    int index;
    int number;
};
```

The first member should look like this:

```
struct structure member0;

member0.index = 0;
member0.number = 23;
```

But I want the program to be able to read lines of any length, so I want a loop that, whenever an integer is read, creates a new member using the number read and a counter that sets the name and index to *previous index + 1* and I would like to know if and how it is possible to do so.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do so, what have you tried?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Use arrays or linked lists?

Comment: Use arrays for this.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) for reading the numbers.

Comment: You should read about the differences between statically typed languages and dynamically typed. Perhaps you better use Python or a similar dynamically typed language.

Comment: You could also make use of data structures like Lists, stacks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done

1. Use `fgets()` to read the line
2. Break the line into tokens using `strtok()`
3. Convert each token to integer using `atoi()` or `strtol()`
4. Keep some variable say `i` which you need to increment for each token and should be reset after each `fgets()` call
5. Have dynamic or static array of your structure to hold the above information

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol()`, you'd want something along this line..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct _TMember
{
    int index;
    int number;
} TMember;

int main()
{
    TMember arr[MAX_SIZE] = {};

    char szNumbers[] = "10 20 30 40 50";
    char *pEnd;

    long int li;
    unsigned short index = 0;
    pEnd = szNumbers;
    for( ; ; )
    {
        char *tmp = pEnd;

        li = strtol( pEnd, &pEnd, 10 );
        if( tmp == pEnd )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[index].index = index;
            arr[index].number = li;
            index++;
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Member %d, idx = %d, number = %d\n", i, arr[i].index, arr[i].number );
    }

    return 0;

}
```